# Is there a way to connect a git repo to 2 remotes at once?

Tags: git, github

I have an ongoing project at my university working as part of a professor's research group. Up until now, I have been using a private repository on my personal Github account to store my work (on `github.com/user/repo`). However, my university also has a separate enterprise Github server, and my professor wants me to also store my work on the university's server (`github.university.com/user/repo`) since that will make handing off the project easier once I leave the group, among other reasons. The issue is that I already have a lot of work done in my personal repo, and I'd like to be able to see it after I'm no longer a student (which will be soon).

My professor doesn't care if I keep my work in my personal repository, as long as it is **also** tracked in the university Github.

I want to know: is there a way to link my existing, private repository to a repository in my university's enterprise Github server? I'd like to:

1. Be able to commit changes to both repos simultaneously (i.e., link to the university GitHub repo and my personal Github repo both at once, and commit changes simultaneously to both with one set of commands, like `git push` to push changes to `github.university.com/user/repo` and `github.com/user/repo` at once)
2. If that's not possible, I'd like to at least retain the commit history of my personal repo when I copy into my university's server, which might be simple but I'm a bit afraid of screwing up my existing work

Beyond simple branching and merging, I'm not great with git, and this sort of niche use-case feels above my pay grade. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/849960/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+remotes

Comment: This is a key aspect of Git being a distributed version-control system. As far as Git is concerned, there is no "central" repository, only repositories *other* than your own. Read [this chapter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) of *Pro Git* for some alternatives to the prevalent centralized workflow.

Comment: *At once:* no. *Sequentially*, sure, but not *at once*. Git makes one connection and starts transferring and that's that. But that should be fine for your purposes: all other repositories are inferior to *this* repository, and so what? :-) (Note that the pronoun *this* moves around, as you move from repository to repository.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to link my existing, private repository to a repository in my university's enterprise Github server

Absolutely. Just add it as a remote:

```
git remote add uni <universityURL>
```

Now when you say

```
git push origin mybranch
```

you are pushing the branch to *your* repo, but when you say

```
git push uni mybranch
```

you are pushing it to the university repo.

(I use this technique all the time, as a backup to my backup. What if GitHub goes down? It does happen. So I also have a Bitbucket account, and I push to both, figuring they won't both be down at once.)

Comment: This was exactly the type of easy solution I was hoping for, thank you, I appreciate the help! It works seamlessly